# How to prove that this function is continuous but not uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am having some troubles solving a question on my homework sheet:

*Prove that $\,\,f:\Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb{R}^n$, defined as $$f(x) = \frac{x}{||x||}$$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.*

I have thought about the case when $\,n=1$, a map sending $\,\Bbb{R}^-$ to $-1$ and $\,\Bbb{R}^+$ to $1$, which is easy to prove. However, what about the cases when $n>1$? I have no idea how to start the $\delta-\epsilon$ statement. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: For continuity you can simply observe that it is the quotient of continuous functions (the norm is a continuous function, precisely because it is the norm).

Comment: The higher dimensional case is very similar to the 1D case, how do you prove that $f$ is not uniformly continuous when $n=1$? Note also that $1D$ case can be "embedded" in the general case: if one has an estimate for $\|f(x)-f(y)\|$ then in the $n$ D case, say $n=3$, you can simply use $(x,0,0)$ and $(y,0,0)$ to give a corresponding estimate for disproving the uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is continuous since $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto\|x\|$ are continuous maps.

Note that for $\delta>0$ we can look at the image of $U_{\delta}=B_{\delta}(0)\setminus\{0\}$ under $f$ and see that $x\in U_{\delta}$ and $-x$ satisfy $\|f(x)-f(-x)\|=2$. Thus $f$ can not be uniformly continuous.

*Additional comment:* if we let $g_{\delta}$ to be the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_{\delta}(0)$, then one can show that $g_{\delta}$ is uniformly continuous. This intuitively shows that the problem about uniform continuity of $f$ is at neighborhoods of the origin and only there.

Comment: thanks, I was just blind of the fact that ||f(x)-f(-x)|| = 2 is also true for higher dimensions.